# Writing output for for loop in different cell id (in excel) using matlab

Tags: matlab, export-to-excel

I have a for loop

> > count=1
> >        for i=4:10
> >                xlswrite('error.xls', 'T', 'Target', ['A' num2str(count)]);
> >                xlswrite('error.xls', testT, 'Target', ['B' num2str(count)]);
> >                xlswrite('error.xls', 'O', 'Output', ['A' num2str(count)]);
> >                xlswrite('error.xls', testy, 'Output', ['B' num2str(count)]);
> >                count=count+1;
> >        end

But its writing the value in different sheet. what I want is in the same sheet the value of **testT** starts from B1 to Q1(say)
and **testy** starts from B2 to Q2

and then for next iteration --- **testT** starts from B6 to Q6(say)
and **testy** starts from B7 to Q7..

I am not able to formulate the logic inside the for loop... so anybody who is good in this please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the data to the same sheet (say, 'Target') and increase the `count` after writing to each row:

```
testT = 1:10;
testy = 1:10;

count = 1;
for i = 4:10
  xlswrite('error.xls', 'T',   'Target', ['A' num2str(count)]);
  xlswrite('error.xls', testT, 'Target', ['B' num2str(count)]);
  count = count + 1;

  xlswrite('error.xls', 'O',   'Target', ['A' num2str(count)]);
  xlswrite('error.xls', testy, 'Target', ['B' num2str(count)]);
  count = count + 1;
end
```